# How to separate an object with keys and values into two arrays

Tags: javascript

I have an object:

```
var myObj = {
  name: 'dri',
  age: '22',
  sex: 'female'
}
```

I need separate the keys and the values in two arrays.

```
var keys = [];
var values = [];
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Hint: `for .. in`, `hasOwnProperty()`, `push()`

Comment: For the keys, `Object.keys()`. For the values, a map of keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var data = {"name": "dri", "age": 22, "sex": "female"};

var data1 = [],
    data2 = [];

for (var property in data) {

   if ( ! data.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      continue;
   }

   data1.push(property);
   data2.push(data[property]);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:-

```
var keys = [];
var values = [];
for (var prop in data) {
   keys.push(prop);
   values.push(data[prop]);
}
```